# For loop returning iterations of same result from OMDB API

Tags: python, api, flask, jinja2

I have been scouring the internet for the answer to this and I am at the point where I feel like I am probably missing something glaringly in my face.

I am attempting to request search results from the omdb api (https://www.omdbapi.com/). I have create countless iterations of the screenshots below, but here is where I am at right now with my code.

Essentially, I am able to see the movie title and year for only the first search result, and I cannot figure out how to loop through each result and display on my webpage. Any help is appreciated.

Code below:

```
(python code)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xVsL.png]
(html)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/crWk7.png]
(terminal)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq65p.jpg]
(webpage result)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLNdF.png]
```

Copy/Pasted Code:

app.py:

```
@app.route('/movies/search_results', methods=['GET'])
def show_search_results():

    """Logic for sending an API request and displaying the JSON response as an HTML. Expects a GET request."""
    
    movies = []
    s = request.args.get("search")

    results = requests.get(f"{API_BASE_URL}search/movies/",params={"s": s}).json()

    results = results['Search']

    for movie in results:
        movies.append(movie)

    return render_template('movies/search_results.html', movies=movies)



@app.route('/movies/detail')
def show_movie_details():
    """For displaying information about the individual movie. Not a list. GET request only."""
    


    movie = requests.get(f'{API_BASE_URL}', params={"i":id})
    print(movie)
    return render_template('movies/detail.html', movie=movie)
```

search_results.html:

```
{% block title %} {% endblock %}

{% block nav1 %} active {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="movie-list">
<div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-center mt-2" style="--bs-gutter-x:0; ">
<p> Search Results for "{{s}}"</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IMDB ID</th>
            <th>Movie Title</th>
            <th>Year Released</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for movie in movies %}

            <tr>
            <td>  
                
                <a href="/movies/detail" id="id">
                        {{ movie['imdbID'] }}
                </a> 
    
            </td> 
            <td>   
                    {{ movie['Title'] }}
            </td> 
            <td>
                {{ movie['Year'] }}
            </td> 

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>              
    </div>
    
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %} {% endblock %}
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="card mb-3">

  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Title: {{ movie['Title'] }}</h5>
  
    <p>
      <span class="text-info">Description: </span> 
    </p>
    <div><h5 class="card-title text-success">Playlists with this movie:</h5></div>

    <p class="card-text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
  

{% endblock %}
```

I did try creating an empty variable, and then assigning the results of my for loop to that variable as an iterable, but I ran into the same problem there too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post all code, input and output, and error messages as plain text.

Comment: When you `return` inside the `for` loop, you end the function and end the loop. So you're only processing the first result.

Comment: @Barmar also yes, the return statement should be tabbed backwards

Comment: @SLDem He also needs to collect all the results into a list.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I have now updated the code per your suggestions and moved my return statement out of the loop, and collected all of the results to a list. Now in my console I am seeing the list of movie results. My final hurdle is getting the information to display on the html page. I will update my code above to reflect the changes!

Comment: so whats the issue right now?

Comment: I have updated the code above. Now I am not able to get the information retrieved from the API to display on my detail page when I click the link on search_results.html

Comment: why do you have two {% block content %} tags?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The first block of HTML above is the search_results.html, the second is detail.html so each one has a block content tag

Answer (score 1):

Try not using the 'page' key in the params dict you are passing in the api request, then you should get all the results.

Also as mentioned in @Barmar comment you are returning your results inside the loop, you should move the return statement one tab to the left.

Comment: It doesn't help if he returns inside the loop.

Comment: in your html it should be not just `title` and `year` but `movie.title` and `movie.year`

Comment: I'm not the OP, it's not my HTML. If you have more you want to add to the answer, use the `Edit` link.

Comment: The problem is in the Python code in the controller.

Comment: I see many problems here haha